# Flutter Android Build failed with an exception 'torch:verifyReleaseResources'

Tags: android, flutter

I'm using [Torch](https://pub.dev/packages/torch#torch) plugin with [Camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) plugin for back flash. It works fine with iOS, but not with Android. When I tried to Create release build for Android it gives me errors.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                                                           

* What went wrong:                                                                                                 
Execution failed for task ':torch:verifyReleaseResources'.                                                         
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade                  
> Android resource linking failed                                                                               
 /Users/apple/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/790c8a51d6267afe36c98b9a0bc454cb/core-1.0.0/res/values/values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

 /Users/apple/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/790c8a51d6267afe36c98b9a0bc454cb/core-1.0.0/res/values/values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.


* Try:                                                                                                             
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                                                                         

BUILD FAILED in 2m 13s                                                                                             
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                                                           
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     134.5s (!)
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin app_review...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                             
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... Done                    0.0s

Sending crash report to Google.
Crash report sent (report ID: 97f69452e4767517)
Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly.
```